Best python models/libraries to extract tables from PDFs
I have some PDFs in which i want to extract the table data,
But the issue is that the table is multi page, I want to detect that multipage table and make it one
, Also there are multiple tables in one pdf so they should not be mixed
Hi
I am looking for some models which can help in extracting the table data from PDF.
I have tried Azure Document Intelligence it is not giving expected results
Here are exact requirements:
a) Able to Detect multiple tables and able to give id for each table to group them
b) One table could be multipage so the model should be able to detect that
c) Able to detect all columns of table

Recommendation questions are off-topic here. Also, there's no programming question, even though you tagged this as [tag:python]. Please read [ask]

Except AI-based tools, I know of no tool that is capable of automatically detecting / joining table fragments across pages.
Custom logic does not count here in my mind: It is always possible to join tables if knowledge about the specific situation can be used.
Based on comparison tests across all files of the standard test bed DocLayNet with over 30 thousand tables contained in more than 18 thousand files, PyMuPDF and pdfplumber can detect more tables than Camelot, and at least PyMuPDF is more than 3 times faster than Camelot.
Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

Please don't answer clearly-off-topic questions. The OP posted a (rambling) bunch of requirements, and no programming question.

I think the best one is GROBID
GROBID: Advanced tool for extracting structured content from PDFs.
Handles complex layouts, multi-page tables.
Camelot> It is best for detecting multiple tables and handling multi-page tables with custom logic.
GROBID is the most robust, but setup and use are more complex.

The question is off-topic. And posting the name of some framework/product/service is not a valid answer.
